# StackPanel / Window width change WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a window, where two vertical -oriented stack panel(left and right) are in the third, horizontal-oriented stackpanel.
Left stack panel holds a number of controls and a button >Hide<, binded to command. And I dlike to animate a "hiding" right stackpanel and resize a window to the width of only left stackpanel. How to do this in the most simple way?
I have found [WPF stackpanel visibilty animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685364/wpf-stackpanel-visibilty-animation)  but , it will not resize a window.

My code is:

```
<Window x:Class="Namespace.MainWindow"
 ...
 x:Name="ololo"
        Height="400" Width="500">
 .....    
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Left" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Command="{Binding HideCommand}">Hide</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="Right" Orientation="Vertical">
            <!--<Controls>-->
            </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Well did you try the linked XAML in a Window's Style?

Comment: I have resource dictionary - there I store styles for textboxes, buttons and fonts - Are you asking about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SizeToContent` property on the `Window` to automatically resize the window when the content changes.

I would recommend the `Width` value.

```
<Window ...
    SizeToContent="Width"
```

However there is one gotcha, which is that you may need to specify the width of each `StackPanel`, or perhaps set a `MinWidth` on your Window to prevent the `Window` from resizing to a 0 width.

Answer (score 1):

Normally animation is done purely in the view, the ViewModel should not have anything to do with the size of your window. So to preserve the MVVM you will just need to adjust the size in the code behind. This normally is by looking up a resource that is the Animation.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="AnimateWindow">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:3.8"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                         From="350"
                         To="100"
                         AccelerationRatio=".1">
        </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

So on the button click you would also need to handle the click event so to fire off the animation. The click event will look up the resource and execute it. It would also handle any other view specific things you need.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var animate= FindResource("AnimateWindow") as Storyboard;
        if (hide != null)
        {
            animate.Begin(this, true);
        }
}
```

This preserves the MVVM and should accomplish what you want.

Comment: How does AnimateWindow knows about left stackpanel?

Comment: The animate.Begin(this,true) is the code behind but the this, in the code behind is the MainWindow itself. So if you are in the usercontrol, you will need to get the window to call the animation.

Comment: I could not acess hide from VM - this is just button on the view, and I think it is never null  after InitializeComponent(); called

Comment: and animate.Begin(this, true); <- why this if this code is in my command function in VM

Comment: You need to do this in the code behind the xaml, not the Viewmodel. Animations and view related things do not go in the viewmodel. You need  to handle your CLICK event.